# Why is the output of my forking program different when I pipe its output?

Tags: c, linux, bash, pipe, fork

I was looking at some simple code on fork, and decided to try it out for myself. I compiled and then ran it from inside Emacs, and got a different output to that output produced from running it in Bash.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  if (fork() != 0) {
    printf("%d: X\n", getpid());
  }

  if (fork() != 0) {
    printf("%d: Y\n", getpid());
  }

  printf("%d: Z\n", getpid());
}
```

I compiled it with gcc, and then ran a.out from inside Emacs, as well as piping it to `cat`, and `grep .`, and got this.

> 2055: X
>   2055: Y
>   2055: Z
>   2055: X
>   2058: Z
>   2057: Y
>   2057: Z
>   2059: Z

This isn't right. Running it just from Bash I get (which I expected)

> 2084: X
>   2084: Y
>   2084: Z
>   2085: Y
>   2085: Z
>   2087: Z
>   2086: Z

*edit - missed some newlines*

What's going on?

Comment: Why are you piping the results through anything (esp. "cat" which really won't do anything at all)? - oh wait it's the piping that introduces the oddity ... hmm ...

Comment: I can reproduce this, so it's not cosmic rays or anything. Intriguing. Note that there's one PID (2056) missing in the former output; that is probably the PID of `cat`.

Comment: I ran it a few times, most of which didn't have missing PIDs.

Comment: For a moment, I thought the use of 'forking' here was meant as a substitute for another word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order in which different processes write their output is entirely unpredictable.  So the only surprise is that sometimes the "X" print statement sometimes happens twice.

I believe this is because sometimes at the second `fork()`, an output line including "X" is in an output buffer, needing to be flushed.  So both processes eventually print it.  Since `getpid()` was already called and converted into the string, they'll show the same pid.

I was able to reproduce multiple "X" lines, but if I add `fflush(stdout);` just before the second `fork()`, I always only see one "X" line and always a total of 7 lines.

Answer (score 8):

I think I know what's going on.  The stdio buffering will be different when output is a tty versus when it's a pipe or a file.  The child processes inherit the parent buffers.  When they're flushed, you can get double output.

If you add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

right after each `printf()` call, you'll see what I mean.

The interesting thing is that it's different when standard output is a tty device.  It may be that the library knows what that means, and flushes after each line break, or something like that.

Comment: Indeed! Putting an `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf` solves it. The contents of the output buffer are copied at the time of the fork, so the same buffered output gets printed twice when the buffer is flushed.

Comment: This is correct.  `stdout` is line-buffered by default when writing to an interactive terminal (so is flushed after each `\n`), but fully buffered when writing to a pipe.  A single `fflush(stdout);` immediately prior to each `fork()` will also work.

Answer (score 6):

So I imagine you are wondering why you are getting more than one "X"?

This is because buffered output is being flushed twice.

When you pipe a program's output, the stdio library recognizes that your output is not a terminal, and it switches to block buffering instead of line buffering. Consequently, there isn't yet any output when the process forks and so now both parent and child have pending output.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used `stdout` at all before forking, you **must** call `fflush(stdout)` before `fork()` (and likewise for any other output `FILE`s you use). Failure to do so results in **undefined behavior**. The effect you're seeing comes from `stdout` being *line-buffered* when it's connected to a terminal, but *fully buffered* when it's connected to a pipe. This is not required, but recommended by the standards (POSIX).